# Call jQuery function several times, and related actions only to siblings

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, alert

I'm making a checklist, in this checklist you can add/remove task, and set a deadline for each task. When the deadline equals the current time, an alert is displayed.

It's working fine when there's only one task, but if I got more tasks, it's only showing an alert for the first task.

When the alert is confirmed, the task's checkbox (green box at right) for alert is unchecked, but this makes all task's alert checkboxes uncheck instead of only the one confirmed.

Guess this needs to be done with an array or so, but I don't get it working.. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Tx in advance!

I'm linking to everything I got in this [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/hBz7R/)

HTML:

```
<div class='todo_list'>
<div class='add_list'>&#43; List</div><br>
<h3 contenteditable='true'>New List</h3>
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type='checkbox' class='task_status'>
        <p class='task' contenteditable='true'> </p>
        <input type='datetime-local'>
        <input type='checkbox' class='alert_status'>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class='add_task'>&#43;</div><br>
</div>
```

jQuery (only part that's going wrong, see fiddle for whole doc)

```
setInterval(function checkAlerts(){
//Set current date & time
var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth()+1;
var day = date.getDate();
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var currentDate = date.getFullYear() + '-' +
((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' + ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + 'T' + ((''+hours).length<2 ? '0' : '') + hours + ':' + ((''+minutes).length<2 ? '0' : '') + minutes;

//Set task deadline
var taskDeadline = $('.alert_status:checked').parent().find("input[type='datetime-local']").val();
//Set task text
var taskText = $('.alert_status:checked').parent().children('p').html()
//Check if task deadline matched current time
if ( currentDate ==  taskDeadline) {
    //If so, give an alert
    if(confirm( taskText ) ){
        //If confirmed, uncheck task alert
        $('.alert_status:checked').prop('checked', false)
    }
    else{
        //Do nothing
    }
};

}, 3000);
```

Comment: The base problem is that the timer is unaware when data has been added or additional items have been appended to the DOM. I added a console log statement http://jsfiddle.net/hBz7R/1/ and taskDeadline is never defined.

Comment: I should say that the taskDeadline is never defined for the list items that are appended. You may need to rethink your logic in order to make this work. A\I also noticed that the checkbox on the right does not remain checked, which will also contribute to the problem.

Comment: Okay, I'll try further. Reason the checkbox is being unchecked after clicking 'ok', is that you've seen the alert. When clicking 'cancel' it stays checked. But guess I need a different approach on this one..

Comment: Yeah, I saw no alert. You'll need to make sure that the user understands what is happening, it needs to be intuitive.

Comment: Hmm maybe you did not see an alert because here in Holland we notate a date with '-' like 2014-10-04, that doesn't match 2014/10/04 so it won't give an alert.. Will need to rethink that too.. haha

Comment: Yeah - you need to be able to accept any date format and then convert that to what you want to use. Or use a datepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go
http://jsfiddle.net/hBz7R/5/

The main change is this...

```
$.each($('.alert_status:checked'), function (index, value) {
   var currentAlert = $(this);
   // your code...
}
```